# IOS image capture and save to UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to capture an image and save it in the imageview. Below is the code.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [_Image setImage:image];
}

- (IBAction)Capture:(UIButton *)sender {
        UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController: cameraUI animated: YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is imagepickercontroller is not called at all!! My .h declaration is

```
@interface AikyaViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

I can get the camera to capture the image, but the image is not saving in my imageview. Infact it is not entering that function itself since its not NSlogging.

Should i have to link anything in the storyboard or any delegates initialisation am i missing?? Plz guide the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo`: is deprecated

change that method with:

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

 NSLog(@"done");

 [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

 [image setImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"]];

}
```

and try to change:

```
- (IBAction)Capture:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    [cameraUI setDelegate:self];

    [cameraUI setAllowsEditing:YES];

    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController: cameraUI animated: YES completion:nil];
  }
```

Comment: Changed, but still the function imagepickercontroller is not being called at all!!